# trying to read mail with mail-listener4 Nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, callback, imap

I am using the sample code provided with the library in npm 
[npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener4)

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener4");

var mailListener = new MailListener({
  username: "******@gmail.com",
  password: "***********",
  host: "imap.gmail.com",
  port: 993, // imap port
  tls: true,
  connTimeout: 10000, 
  authTimeout: 5000, 
  debug: console.log, 
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
  searchFilter: ["ALL"], 
  markSeen: true, 
  fetchUnreadOnStart: false, 
  mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, 
  attachments: true, 
  attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } 
   });

mailListener.start(); // start listening

mailListener.on("error", function(err){
    console.log(err);
 });
```

this is the function that's called when a mail is recived : 
but i don't know how it works

```
   mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
         console.log("emailParsed");
         // I know that i should get the mail body here 
         // but i don't know how 

     });



mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment){
   console.log(attachment.path);
  });
```

i want to get the body of the mail as a string or xml 
that's what i get on the console when i recive a mail 
[secreenshoot after reciving a mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V9oS.png)